# Graph modelling: Forbidden paths

Tags: graph-theory, quickgraph

I am modelling a system where I believe a directed graph is the method of choice.
However I am facing the following issue which seems trivial but I cannot solve:

Having three vertices A, B, C, how do I model the graph such that there is a path from

> A->B and B->A,
>
> A->C and C->A

but

> *not* B->C nor C->B.

The issue I am facing is that of course the path from B to C via A (B->A->C) would be legal, which in reality it is not.

How do I solve this? Use different vertices (e.g. additional ones)?

The directed graph is necessary due to other constaints (think a vertex D with A->D only)

Comment: So, given a graph with these types of connections, you need to remove them from the graph? what kind of domain is generating this kind of graph and why does this property then need to be removed?

Comment: Why do you want to model it as a graph ? What properties of graphs are you planning on using ? What is the size of the data ?